# css how to wrap text with dots

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

This looks duplicate but didn't find answer which fix my issue, hence posting.

Basically I wanted to wrap text using css, here is the sample text which i wanted to wrap

> "This is really really long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long  sentence"
>
> "........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................."

The below css wrap first line (This is really really long....sentence) properly in all browsers.

The second line, multiple dots, only get wrapped in chrome browser, rest other browser, like edge, firefox, IE, shows single line dots

```
.wrap-line-content {
        overflow: hidden;
        word-break: break-word;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
```

This is the output in IE

[image]

Any idea how we can fix wrap issue with dots?

Comment: `word-break: break-all;` ?

Comment: Nope, its same issue. Interestingly firefox doesn't identify word-break: break-word. If i put both break-word and break-all then it works for chrome and firefox  but IE and Edge same issue

Comment: yes only chrome support it check the bottom table here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break

Comment: Thanks Temani, initially i used break-all but it was not working anywhere, hence changed to break-word but definitely this i can't use for all browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<style> 
.wrap-line-content {
    word-wrap: break-word;  /* important */ 
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="wrap-line-content">......................................</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

Create a div around your content like so:

```
<div class="bottom-dot"><p>long long long long long long long long long long</p></div>
```

Then, as CSS:

```
.bottom-dot {border-bottom: 2px dotted black;}
```

Let me know if this works for you! Did this work? If so, vote it up! :)

Comment: I guess you didn't get my question properly...i want to wrap dots which is already part of the text